# HTML - Size limit for text and number on the same input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code for put limits on input area.

```
<input type="text" name="myinput" maxlength="10">
```

This code just work for text. I want to add max 4 for int and max 6 for text

**Success example:**

input: abdc123d 
input: 1234abcde

**Not possible:**

input: 123456789 
input: dasdsadsa

Comment: html doesnt have that option. U will require javascript/jquery

Comment: You should add an attribute called "pattern" to your html input tag. There you must include a regular expression to validate the input text what you want

Comment: You can use this simple pattern `pattern="([A-Za-z]{6})|([0-9]{4})"` for your input.

Comment: @nstungcom this will not work. Look at first input, he wish to have numbers and letters in any possible combination, not in a specific one.

Comment: @Vykintas Oh well, my bad.

Comment: I guess you could parse each individual character in the input and check if it's a number or not, and for every number and every non-number, add to seperate counts. It'd be some pretty long-whinded validation, though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that add a .bad class.

You could then check for .bad class on saving etc..

```js
$('input').on('input', function () {
  var $t = $(this),
      val = $t.val(),
      wantlen = 6;
  if (parseInt(val).toString() === val) {
    wantlen = 4;    
  }
  
  $t.toggleClass('bad', val.length > wantlen);  
});
```

```css
input {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.bad {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text"> <br/>

<input type="text">
```